# Create inline CKeditor from a draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor

I would like to apply CKeditor on items that have been dragged (jquery UI). Here is my code:

```
$ ('sidebar-nav. box.'). draggable ({
    connectToSortable '. column'
    helper 'clone'
    handle '. drag'
    stop: function (e, t) {
         CKEDITOR.inline (t.helper);
    }
});
```

And here is my error (in Ckeditor.js file) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Is this the right way? It seems it can not find the item.

Comment: What is `t.helper`? DOM object? jQuery object? String?

Comment: It's a Jquery Object, regarding to JQUERY UI API documentation.

Comment: So if you use the latest CKEditor (with jQuery adapter), call `t.helper.ckeditor()`. `CKEDITOR.inline` will work for native DOM elements, CKEditor elements and strings: retrieve it from `t.helper` to do it that way.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know we can call ckeditor in that way. But, I have nothing when I use it, no error, nothing.. I will check the official documentation.